# Redux - How to await getting the state from useSelector

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

What is the best way to await the data coming from `useSelector`. What I mean by this is that I have a `async action` which is being dispatched using `redux-thunk` or to be precise `createAsyncThunk`. Everything works really fine with dispatch but the problem I am having is that I want to show certain component and pass the `state` from the `useSelector` as a prop.

Since it is the `async action` it needs to wait a little bit to get me the data, but I need that data to show the users a certain component just like I said, so I am passing the `state` as a prop, but I end up having a `null` value since I passed the prop before I got the data back. I am also using the `Firebase` as a, lets say API.

This is my code:

```
const ProfileSection = () => {
  const [account, setAccount] = useState([]);
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);
  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(authFirebase, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        dispatch(getUser(user.email));
        setAccount(user);
      }
    });
  }, [user]);

  console.log(account);

  return (
    <>
      {account && (
        <Container className="py-5">
          <div className="profile-section">
            <Row>
              <ProfileData user={account[0]} />
              <ProfileForm user={account[0]} />
            </Row>
          </div>
        </Container>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

As you can see the components `ProfileData` and `ProfileForm` are using this state as a prop.

I have an **idea** where I would just use the `useEffects` on both of the components.

Also, I need this `state` to get default value to a `useState` state.

This is what I mean by this:

```
 const initialState = {};
  if (user) {
    initialState.firstName = user.firstName;
    initialState.email = user.email;
    initialState.lastName = user.lastName;
  }

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialState);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no waiting in React. Your component has to render the instant the parent component renders a `<ChildComponent>`. That will change in the future with React Suspense, but at the moment that is how React works.

Your component will have to take in account that it will be rendered before data is ready, check for that and in that case do something like `return <div>loading...</div>` instead of trying to access the data.